# BPM analysis of streamed audio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, ffmpeg, audio-player

I need to determine bpm from streamed audio, like playing YouTube, bandcamp, mixcloud, etc., so the input has to be the current audio device, not a file.

I am struggling to find the correct options with sox / bpm-tools.

Any hints how to do that (or other means how to do the trick)?

```
$ arecord -L
default 
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC255 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC255 Analog
    Front speakers
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC255 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC255 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC255 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC255 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```